# About binary tree rotations

Tags: tree, binary-tree, pascal

Im trying to program an AVL on pascal. I already programmed a regular binary tree and it works, im trying to make a self-balanceable one, and i have encountered a problem.

I have a subtree i want to rotate, and the thing is i don't know how to assign the parent of the subtree root node pointer. Meaning given the next tree:
root node of the subtree i want to rotate = 30
parent node of the subtree = 55

```
          55                                      55          
       30    60            ----->           45         60         
   10    45    75                        30   50          75       
  5  15    50    90                     10                    90
                                      5    15
```

how am i supposed to change the pointer that goes from 55 to 30, to go from 55 to 45?
Most of the code i've seen doesnt have a pointer that goes from a node to its parent so i dont know how to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not showing any code, but normally you would do something along the lines of

```
Root := Root.Rebalance;
```

That is, you call on the sub-tree to re-balance itself, and that re-balancing function returns the root as its result. That result may be the same root as previously or - as in your scenario - a new root node.